# Magento 2 - export adminthml translations only?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

**Is there a way to export to csv file only translations that are used for magento admin?**

If I would use "**bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases ...**" command, it will export everything to csv file, but I would like to know is there a way to get only the ones from magento admin? I dont believe that there is a solution for that but you never know.

I need to differentiate somehow which phrases are for adminhtml and which ones are for frontend, that is why I am asking if there is a ways to get only one of these two types.

Thank you all in advance!